# Использование данных из формы?

Tags: javascript, ajax

На сайте есть форма обратной связи.

Отправка данных происходит без перезагрузки страницы при помощи

```js
$('#osForm').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "mail.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#osForm').serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
      $.fancybox.close();
      $.fancybox.open({
        src: '#p_ok',
        type: 'inline',
      });
    },
    error: function(response) {
      //обработка ошибок при отправке
    }
  });
});
```

Но мне нужно что бы после отправки имя из формы подставилось в окне `#p_ok` которое всплывает после отправки формы с сообщением об успехе.

Как можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#osForm').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: "mail.php",
    type: "post",
    data: $('#osForm input').val()
  })
  done(function(data) {
    $('#p_ok').html($('#osForm input').val())  // success
  })
  fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus ); // error 
  });
});
```